# Check if a url parameter exists and render approprietly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a URL in this format `http://0.0.0.0:3000/#&ui-state=dialog`. I want to check for the existence of `ui-state` so I can render approprietly a page. I tried this

```
params.has_key?(:'ui-state')
```

But it did not work.

How can I check for the existence of ui-state?

---

Solution

I am using jQuery mobile. What seems like a url parameter is actually an internal attribute of jQuery mobile. That's the reason why there are no `?`.

Comment: Wait, what is your full URL? from your partial example, it appears you have `/&ui-state` instead of `/?ui-state`.  The query string must begin with `?`.

Comment: I posted the full URL. There are no `?` : `http://0.0.0.0:3000/#&ui-state=dialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the partial example URL you posted (`http://.../&ui-state=dialog`)  is your actual URL, it is incorrect. Your query string must begin with a `?` as in `http://.../?ui-state=dialog`.  An `&` cannot start the querystring.

#### Update

Since this is from jQuery and not a real URL parameter, it won't appear in `params` in Rails. Instead you'll need to parse it out of the `request.url`:

```
ui_state = /&ui-state=([a-z]+)$/.match(request.url)
puts ui_state[1]
```

#### Update2

Since the `&ui-state` follows the url hash `#`, it will not be available in the `request.url`.  The hash is strictly a client-side component used by the browser, and isn't sent to the server in the HTTP request.

Comment: I had tried this too, but no chance. Here is the complete URL in localhost : `http://0.0.0.0:3000/#&ui-state=dialog`

Comment: @JustinDomingue That isn't valid. The ui-state won't be read as a parameter unless it appears after `?`

Comment: I understood the error : I edited my first post. I guess I will need to use regular expression on the url?

Comment: @JustinDomingue Yes, if it isn't a real URL param you cannot get it from `params`.  You'll have to parse it out of the `request.url`.

Comment: I have this `<% unless /&ui-state=([a-z]+)$/.match(request.url) %><a href="/recherche"...` but when I go a page containing `ui-state` in its url, it still renders `<a href=...`. Did I forget something?

Comment: @JustinDomingue Ahh, I didn't see the hash `#` in your URL. That isn't going to be passed to the server. The hash is strictly used by the browser, and isn't part of the request, so if `ui-state` follows `#` it won't even be sent.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `params[:ui-state] == dialog` or `params[:ui-state].blank?` / `params[:ui-state] == ""`

Comment: When I type `params[:ui-state]` I get an error `undefined variable state`. I have to type `:'ui-state'`.